# Manually packaging data for CakePHP's save()

Tags: php, cakephp, save

I'm trying to package up some data for the save() function in cakephp.  I'm new to PHP, so I'm confused about how to actually write the below in code:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [fieldname1] => 'value'
            [fieldname2] => 'value'
        )
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly you want ? Where you facing problem ?

Comment: I am not using any forms, but I need to save some data into the database.  I have a Followers Model with two tables: user_id and follower_id.  I'm trying to create a $data package to manually create and save() using cakephp.  But I read that in order to use the save() function, I first must put the $data array into the appropriate format.

Comment: Yes , you have to use the above format...But I still not getting why you don't have any form ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question, you can create the array structure you need, and save it, by doing this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'ModelName' => array(
        'fieldname1' => 'value',
        'fieldname2' => 'value'
    )
);
$this->ModelName->save($data);
?>
```

**Please note:**
Based on what you've written above in your comments it looks like you're not keeping to the CakePHP conventions. It's possible to do things this way but you'll save yourself a lot of time and trouble if you decided to stick with the CakePHP defaults as much as possible, and only do it your own way when you have a good reason to.

A couple things to remember are:

1. Model names should be singular. This means that your model should be called Follower instead of Followers.
2. The model's primary key in the database should be named just `id`, not `followers_id`, and should be set as PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT in your database.

If you decide not to follow the conventions you'll probably find yourself scratching your head, wondering why things aren't working, every step of the way. Try having a look at the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do like below:

```
$this->Followers->create();
$this->data['Followers']['user_id'] = $user_id;

$this->data['Followers']['follower_id'] = $follower_id; // If it is primary and auto increment than you don't need this line.

$this->Followers->save($this->data)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this right now!  PS. I don't know if I'm doing things correctly, but for one particular area in my site, I'm not using a form helper, but I still need to create and save into the db.

Comment: Also equivalent: `$this->Followers->save(array('Followers' => array('user_id' => $user_id, 'follower_id' => $follower_id)));`